# WPF: bind to the first item in the sorted ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, sorting, binding

I have a ListView with items, that contain string field `Name` among others. Items in the ListView are sorted by this field:

```
SortDescription descr = new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
list.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(descr);
```

I also have a TextBlock in which I want to display the Name of the first item in the sorted ListView. Items can be added, removed and edited at runtime, so I would like to use some kind of binding like the following one (doesn't work, just for example):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=list, Path=Items[0].Name}"/>
```

1) How can I achieve the desired behavior using a binding?

2) If such binding can't be created, which is the most convenient way to succeed?

Any thoughts and hints would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Content of the main window:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="nameFirst" Text="{Binding ElementName=list, Path=Items[0].Name}"/>
    <ListView Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWnd, Path=List}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Loaded="list_Loaded"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public Item(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set 
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> _list;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set 
        { 
            _list = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        List.Add(new Item("1"));
        List.Add(new Item("2"));
        List.Add(new Item("3"));
    }

    private void list_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SortDescription descr = new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Descending);
        list.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(descr);
    }
}
```

When the application is started, items in the ListView are sorted in the descending order: "3", "2", "1", but nameFirst TextBox still displays "1", though now it should display "3".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you wrote should do the work. The problem is probably not in the xaml.

You said the items contains a **field** Name. WPF can only bind to **public properties** make sure to use them, and not public members. It's also possible you're seeing old values if you changed them after the window was opened. Make sure your items implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and the properties invoke `OnPropertyChanged`.

If you're still having problems, please post more of your code, specifically your data items class and the place where you set the SortDescriptor.

Lastly, though it's not what you asked about. You can bind to the **current** item in an array by using the `/` operator. To use your code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=list, Path=Items/Name}"/>
```

You control the "current" item using [`CollectionViews`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) and the [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) property.

Comment: Yes, the binding `Binding ElementName=list, Path=Items[0].Name` binds the text to the `Name` property, but it won't be updated if the items are sorted. For example, there are two items: "2" and "1" (in the order in which they lay in the ListView's source). When items are sorted, "1" stands before "2", but Item[0] remains "2".

Comment: Sorry, to be more exact, Item[0] will be changed to "1" internally, but the binding won't be updated and will still bind text to the "2" value.

Comment: @undermind - Try using `ObservableCollection` as the collection to the list's ItemsSource. And please post more of your code. The problem isn't in the code you posted, and I can only guess when regarding the rest.

Comment: Updated the question with the code. Sorry for the delay.